# What value of K parameter of the following two vectors?

Tags: quantum-state

I have two vectors:
$$
a=\begin{pmatrix}
{1} & {1} & {1} \
\end{pmatrix} \\
b=\begin{pmatrix}
{1} & {2} & {k} \
\end{pmatrix}
$$
These vectors should be orthogonal. What is value of $k$?

Comment: I would recommend to post questions on mathematics here: https://math.stackexchange.com/. This forum is focussed mainly on quantum computing but your question is concerning linear algebra.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't specifically relevant to quantum computing or quantum information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\left\langle a| b \right\rangle=
\begin{pmatrix}
{1} & {1} & {1} \
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
{1} & {2} & {k} \
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since the two vectors are orthogonal,so the inner product of them is zero:
$$
0=1+2+k \\
k=-3
$$

Comment: Just note that this is valid only in case so-called standard inner product. Generaly the inner product is defined as $x^{T}Ax$ where $A$ is positive matrix. Apparently $A=I$ for standard inner product. I suppose the standard product was meant in the question.